# How to load images in tableView after a bit of delay?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4

I have seen an app called ZuluTrade, which has a charts in there tableView cells.

Basically it seems to be images in tableViewCell's imageView.

When the page loads the tableView displays the text first and then it loads the images into the tableViewCell as we scroll through the tableView.

This helps to improve the performance because the user does not have to wait till all things are loaded into the cell and also it makes tableView scrolling smooth.

How can that feature be achieved?

Here are the screenshots of the app:

[image]

[image]

Code in my tableView `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *MyIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyIdentifier %i", indexPath.row];

MyTableCell *cell = (MyTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
//if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[MyTableCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];


    NSString *testVal = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] valueForKey:@"idValue"];

    if (testVal == (NSString *)[NSNull null]) {
        testVal = @"NULL";
    }
    //NSLog(@"testVal : %@",testVal);
NSLog(@"Fund Name : %@",[[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"FundName"]);

    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dtFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dtFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *dtString = [dtFormat stringFromDate:date];

  NSString *fundname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"FundName"]];


NSString *imageName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@.png",fundname,dtString]; 
//NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *documentsDirectory = [self getImagePath];
NSLog(@"Image Path : %@",documentsDirectory);
NSError *error1;
NSString *filepath1;
NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error1];
if (files == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error reading contents of documents directory: %@", [error1 localizedDescription]);
}
NSLog(@"FileName: %@",imageName);
BOOL success = NO;
for (NSString *file in files)
{
    NSLog(@"file in Files is %@",file);
    if([file isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageName]])
    {
        filepath1 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
        NSLog(@"Full Path :%@",filepath1);
        success = YES;
    }
}




    if(success == YES)
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filepath1];
    }
    else if(success != YES)
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newfund.png"];
    }


    UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60.0, 0, 120.0, 
                                                                tableView.rowHeight)] autorelease]; 
    [cell addColumn:50];
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.tag = LABEL_TAG; 
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]; 
    //NSLog(@"%@",[[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"FundName"]);
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"FundName"]];
    //NSLog(@"FundName: %@",label.text);
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter; 
    //label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor]; 
    label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | 
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; 
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];        

return cell;
}
```

Comment: You should the code your have for -tablView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method, that way we can provide tips on how to improve it.

Comment: Ok I will post the code soon.

Comment: @Black Frog: I have posted the code. Please check it out

Comment: @Parth, doing a quick review, I would add a break statement after you find the file you are looking for. Also, why are you creating a brand new string for the comparison?  You should just do `if([file isEqualToString:imageName])`

Comment: @PARTH, how big are these png files?

Comment: @Black Frog: png files are of 4 KB.

Comment: @Black Frog: I tried changing all as you said but still doesnt improve the performance. Now I want to load images as Lazy Table Images but the images are in my app's Document directory. So is there a way we can use Lazy table images with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add images from documents directory and add them late into the table view as Lazy table images.

For that you can use the following

Take a look at the SDWebImage repository link below.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#readme

This would help you out.

Now there you need to make one small change:

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:test1.png]
           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

in place of

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:test1.png]
           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Happy to Help :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you configure a cell in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you should check, if image is loaded (if it's so - display it from there).

And when images are loaded (all or just some of them), you should call `reloadData` / `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` / `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:`) of your table view to drop old generated table cells from cache.

*UPDATE:*

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        UIImageView *imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
        imgView.hidden = YES;
        imgView.tag = 5555;
        [cell addSubview:imgView];
    }

    if (nil != _images[indexPath.row]) {
        UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:5555];
        imgView.image = _images[indexPath.row];
        [imgView sizeToFit];
        imgView.hidden = NO;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

And _images[] here is the container with images for cells (UIImage pointers). I suppose that we have only one section to let myself use some simple container in this example. Here _images[] stores nil if image wasn't loaded, otherwise - necessary UIImage*.

In some method, which is called on image load, you should do these steps:

1. Save image for corresponding _images[] index.
2. Call tableView's `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` for necessary section & row (from main thread, of course).

Comment: +1 for quick reply and Thanks for the help.I am not very clear with what you said. Can you please explain it in more detail?

Comment: Hey kpower can you give some example? or link to some article which discusses this thing?

Answer (score 1):

One way might be, when you load a cell, you can start a new thread to load the image.

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadData:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Then in the same class you need the method to do work and a call back.

```
-(void) loadData:(id)object
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    //do stuff here
    [pool release];
    //Call back
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadDataComplete:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}


-(void) loadDataComplete:(id)object
{
    // Maybe be more clever and pass the indexPath around so you can just load that row.
    [tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the cell is first visible, the method `tablView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called to display the text. Mark the cell as visible. Load in the image using an asynchronous thread (subclass NSOperation). When the image is ready for a particular cell then send `–reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to the table view to load that particular row from the concurrent thread. I wouldn't use `reloadData` since that will cause all data in the table to be reloaded and will probably impact scrolling performance.

Answer (score 0):

check out [LazyTableImages sample code by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

> This sample demonstrates a multi-stage approach to loading and
>   displaying a UITableView. It begins by loading the relevant text from
>   an RSS feed so the table can load as quickly as possible, and then
>   downloads the images for each row asynchronously so the UI is more
>   responsive.